# Size of fullscreen activity background image

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a app that uses a full screen activity with a background bitmap, how big background image do I need to avoid up scaling of the background image? I have read somewhere that the different sizes is

```
screen size size is at least    size can be upto
xlarge      960dp x 720dp       1920dp x 1080dp
large       640dp x 480dp       960dp x 720dp
normal      470dp x 320dp       640dp x 480dp
smal        426dp x 320dp       470dp x 320dp
```

If I don't want up scaling or stretching of the full screen activities background bitmap it should be of size

```
xlarge      1920dp x 1080dp
large       960dp x 720
normal      640dp x 480dp
smal        470dp x 320dp
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my experience:

hdpi:

- 480 x 800
- 480 x 852
- 540 x 960
- 1024 x 600 (old 7" tablet)
- 1280 x 800 (7" tablet)

xhdpi:

- 720 x 1280 (not sure, I don't have this kind of device)
- 1080 x 1920
- 1920 x 1080 (10" tablet)

So you still have to make your background image scale-able......